# Upload a custom csv file, read contents and delete that file

Tags: uploads

Can someone please direct me to a resource or give me some pointers on:

- How to upload a csv file to wordpress (media uploader or alternate methods, ajax powered preferred)
- Access that file so I can read the contents

I am not looking for a plugin as this is a custom file that I need to read and process inside a plugin.  Ideally, this workflow is desired: **Choose a file** > **Click Upload** > **Plugin accesses the file after upload** and processes file content > **Plugin deletes the file**.  Bold steps interest me the most.

Comment: Without describing what "process file contents" means, your question is hard to answer.

Comment: @chrisguitarguy Basically read the file content and do stuff with it (db and some misc. operations).  That part I already have. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Enable upload of CSV files, which are not in the default allowed files ([see here](http://www.wprecipes.com/wordpress-tip-allow-upload-of-more-file-types))
2. Hook into [add_attachment](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/add_attachment) action hook to detect when the desired file is uploaded
3. Do whatever you need to do using that hook, then trigger [wp_delete_attachment](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_delete_attachment) once the file has been processed.

Depending on what you want to do, it may be beneficial to craft your own upload setup outside the default Media Manager where it would be easier to detect when a file uploaded should be processed by your plugin.

Comment: I ended up using the default media uploader and am hooking into 'wp_handle_upload', which gives me the file path.  Thanks!

Comment: Glad to help! If everything worked out, would you mind marking this question as resolved? Thanks!